# Should the Ram chip color match the motherboard color in a brand new laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, colors

Here is the case, I have given my sony laptop to a technician and (because i was dumb and busy) did not take serial numbers for parts or even take a look at them, so i decided to do that after i took it back from him and I noticed that the RAM card (green) is a different color from the motherboard (blue) so im afraid he substituted mine with a faulty one or something it was also made by Samsung..

Absolutely experienced users please only reply

Comment: Samsung make memory for a lot of suppliers (in fact I'm pretty sure Sony do not make memory) so it is entirely reasonable to expect to see Samsung memory in a Sony laptop. If you are worried about it being bad quality, do an extended memory test on your laptop using memtest or similar.

Comment: Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no correlation between memory stick PCB colour and the motherboard colour. A manufacturer will choose whatever parts meet specifications and cosmetic choices will be completely secondary.

It is quite common to have Green memory sticks, blue motherboards, red graphics cards and black whatever else's. Or you could have a green motherboard and black memory sticks. The colour is entirely irrelevant to how the components actually function and while some manufacturers might use colour to separate product lines it has zero effect on performance.

What you should check is that you have the correct size and speed of RAM, and that it is from a good manufacturer. The colour is useless and tells you nothing except someone said "I'd like you to paint it red".

Source: Electronics engineer that's seen the inside or more laptops and computers than you've probably ever used.